# Convert lambda type from int => IEnumerable<string>> to int => Task<IEnumerable<string>>>?

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I have a method

```
string M1(Func<int x, Task<IEnumerable<string>>> getList) 
// getList: int => Task<IEnumerable<string>>>
{ ...... }
```

How to make the parameter of M1 in the following to type `int => Task<IEnumerable<string>>>`.

```
var l = new List<string>(); .... // l is pre-built
var r = M1(x => l); // The type of param is int => IEnumerable<string>>
```

`async x => l` will give a warning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Task.FromResult()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194922(v=vs.110).aspx) to create a task with a result already in the completed state.

```
var l = new List<string>(); .... // l is pre-built
var r = M1(x => Task.FromResult<IEnumerable<string>>(l));
```

Comment: How it compares with `async x => l`? which will give a warning.

Comment: It will do the same logic as `async x => l` but it will do it without a warning and without extra code generated by the compiler behind the scenes. Any time you see that warning you can usually just use `Task.FromResult<T>()` as the object you return to solve the problem.

Comment: [Here is a DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/89Luwb) showing the two. See how the version with FromResult has no `!` next to it.